# kubernetes-scdf error: [io-9393-exec-10] o.s.c.d.s.k.AbstractKubernetesDeployer : An error has occurred

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I created a spring-cloud-dataflow pod on my own k8s cluster . And the error occured when I deploy a stream on the scdf.

Logs are the below :

```
2017-02-01 15:04:56.121 ERROR 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-5] o.s.c.d.s.k.AbstractKubernetesDeployer   : An error has occurred.
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
  at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:57) ~[kubernetes-client-1.4.14.jar!/:na]
......
2017-02-04T08:01:19.721241000Z Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to kubernetes.default.svc/10.254.0.1:443
2017-02-04T08:01:19.721387000Z  at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:187) ~[okhttp-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
2017-02-04T08:01:19.721537000Z  at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:170) ~[okhttp-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
2017-02-04T08:01:19.721684000Z  at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:111) ~[okhttp-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
2017-02-04T08:01:19.721883000Z  at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:187) ~[okhttp-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
2017-02-04T08:01:19.722037000Z  at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123) ~[okhttp-3.3.1.jar!/:na]
  ... 77 common frames omitted
2017-02-01 15:04:56.121  WARN 1 --- [nio-9393-exec-5] o.s.c.d.s.c.StreamDeploymentController   : Exception when deploying the app StreamAppDefinition [streamName=ticktock, name=time, registeredAppName=time, properties={spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.requiredGroups=ticktock, spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=ticktock.time}]: An error has occurred.
```

Comment: Does your apiserver log anything related to that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I had resolved this problem . It was caused by the certificates .